why I receive Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: HmacSHA256
I am using JWT Authentication. I received many errors and exceptions, and was not able to receive the token.
But finally I succeed to receive the token, but now I receive another error message:
The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: HmacSHA256

I have the SecurityConfig.class :
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    private final UserAuthenticationEntryPoint userAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    private final UserAuthProvider userAuthProvider;

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("X-Requested-With", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept","Token", "Authorization"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(
                HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                HttpHeaders.ACCEPT

        ));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .exceptionHandling((exception) -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(userAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthFilter(userAuthProvider), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login", "/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()));
        return http.build();
    }


    }

and also I have UserAuthProvider.class :
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class UserAuthProvider {
    @Value("${security.jwt.token.secret-key}")
    private String secretKey;

    private final UserService userService;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init(){
        // this is to avoid having the raw secret key available in the JVM
        secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());
    }

    public String createToken(String login){

        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime()+3_600_000_000L);

        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secretKey);

        String token  = JWT.create()
                .withIssuer(login)
                .withIssuedAt(now)
                .withExpiresAt(validity)
                .sign(Algorithm.HMAC256(secretKey));
        return  token;
    }
    public Authentication validateToken(String token){
        JWTVerifier verifier=  JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(secretKey)).withIssuer("http://localhost:3000").build();
        DecodedJWT decoded = verifier.verify(token);    
        UserDTO user = userService.findByLogin(decoded.getIssuer());
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, Collections.emptyList());
    }

}

My JWT Filter class is :
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final UserAuthProvider userAuthProvider;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String header = httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (header != null) {
            String[] elements = header.split(" ");
            if (elements.length == 2 && "Bearer".equals(elements[0])) {
                try {
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                            userAuthProvider.validateToken(elements[1])
                    );
                } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}

And UserAthenticationEntryPoint class :
 @Component
public class UserAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void commence(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), new ErrorDTO("Unauthorized path"));

    }
}

In Browser I receive error 401 (Unauthorized), as I understand that due to this error, because the server side can not validate the token signature. here is output in console:
___________________________________________ HEADERS __________________________________________________
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJxd2UiLCJpYXQiOjE3MTczMjI4NDgsImV4cCI6MTcyMDkyMjg0OH0.Kue9qeVyZAsNCIFrGj8WRYKmZejN_tlPmrTkLtajOX4
___________________________________________ HEADERS __________________________________________________
2024-06-03T17:39:04.305+03:00 ERROR 5612 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.SignatureVerificationException: The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: HmacSHA256
    

And as I understand that next errors I receive because my backend cannot validate the token signature...:
2024-06-03T17:39:04.313+03:00 ERROR 5612 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.art.jwt.backend.dto.ErrorDTO and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)


2024-06-03T17:39:04.315+03:00 ERROR 5612 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing [ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]]

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.art.jwt.backend.dto.ErrorDTO and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
    

And the main problem is - why it cannot validate this token. According the resources in Internet, it should work....
here is my POM.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.art.jwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Backend</name>
    <description>Demo spring with JWT</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.26</lombok.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                    <version>6.5.2.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

The yml configs I have the next :
security:
  jwt:
    token:
     secret-key: my-secret-key

spring:
  datasource:
#    platform: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/backenddb
    username: artiom
    password: admin
#    initialization-mode: always
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create

For me it seams correct....so far should not give me such errors and outputs - I thought, but i have what i have....
Probably you can see the mistake....

That doesn't directly answer your question, but I see some issues. First of all, your token should contain all the necessary information to save in context. It's a very bad idea to reach the database with every user request. Instead, you can do this when building the token for the user - just save this information as one of the custom claims.
Another thing is that you use a secret key to create security keys. It's a better idea to generate a key pair to create the token with a private key and validate it with a public key. This approach is also helpful if you want to separate the login process from validation or move to a microservice architecture.

It is good advice for the future improvements. Thanks for that. But first I am trying to understand how it works in spring. I read about private key and refresh key. This is in the plan. But in my current plans it is solve this issue...
